# how to wire from power to slide switch on easyeda

Tags: switches, easyeda

I'm trying to wire from power to the middle part of my switch
(SW-TH_SS-12F45-GXXX <-- name) when i bring a combined wire from my positive and negative ports to connect it it doesn't show the icon for wire connection
(white dot in center of pin) nor will it let me connect it.[image]

Comment: Why would you want to connect both positive and Negative power terminals to the same terminal of a switch?  That would create a short circuit.  What does your schematic show for those connections?  By the way, we use "U" reference designators for ICs - those 2-terminal parts you've designated "U2, U4, and U10 are probably resistors or capacitors which should have "R" or "C" reference designators.